# Eradication of HIV

Tags: virology, hiv

If the last person with AIDS dies, does that mean the disease/virus has been eradicated forever?

Since the disease can ever only be transmitted, shouldn't it be possible to completely remove it from the face of the earth?

Comment: are you suggesting to eliminate the potential sources for hiv,this sounds a little too extreme for my taste.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have with references to reliable sources. ——— The [US CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/su48a7.htm) is one potential source of information — many more can be found by searching for "disease eradication criteria". Thanks! 

Comment: Sir my apologies if it sounded extreme, it was just a simple question in my head.